# android file upload with resume facility

Tags: android

I want to design system that allow user upload files. But it should have resume facility in case of internet connection lost.
so user do not need to always start from zero

any suggestion how to implement this?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a proper question and improve yours according the guidelines. At first you should share some code you already tried and whats wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

When you selecting file from directory then you have to save the file path in preference, database etc...
And write one bound service for upload the file. Or you can use NOT_STICKY service.
If any case you lost your internet then no need to start from zero, you just pass the file path which you have stored in preference and fire the service again.

Answer (score 0):

try this good library it handles all the scenarios:
[Easily upload files (FTP / Multipart / Binary) in the background with progress indication notification](https://github.com/gotev/android-upload-service)